# Record presentation from PDF with presenter face in corner

Tags: screen-recording, presentation, video-recording

I need to record a presentation and would like to include a video of my face in a corner, such as in this example:

[image: screenshot from presentation video]
*Source: Matthew Rocklin / coiled [via YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_GRK4L-bnw)*

I am preparing my presentation with LaTeX, so my presentation file will be in Portable Document Format (PDF).  I have access to Linux and Windows machines.  An offline Linux solution is preferred.

With a Google Search, I find only solutions for Microsoft Powerpoint.  Since I'm using other software to prepare my presentation, those solutions are not useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Free and Open Source Software (FOSS) [Open Broadcaster Software (OBS) Studio](https://obsproject.com/welcome) appears to have a rich selection of features that may allow doing exactly what you need.  I haven't tried it yet, but it appears to let users select multiple sources (such as a webcam or an application window) for recording and arrange those on the screen.  That should allow for a presenter video in a corner of the presentation.  It also allows for filters to be applied to those sources; perhaps that allows for the outline/transparency visible in the dask video.